# Does cross-chain exchange on a DEX-es obfuscate the source or chain of the coins when the new owner gets them?

Tags: decentralized-exchange

Let's say, I have Ethereum and someone has Polkadot. If we go to a cross-chain DEX and exchange our coins, then I'll get Polkadot and the other party will get Ethereum.

Do I understand correctly that such **cross-chain** exchange operation **on a DEX** will errase, at least to some degree, all the data that might've led to identifiying the previous owner on of either coins?

In other words, my new coins, Polkadot, as well as the Ethereum of the other party. would be as if they were just mined. Right? Namely,  **with no trace** to their previous lifes assossiated with their previous owners.

Comment: No, they could hide some details at some degree but it is not their purpose, a dedicated actor could easily match the transactions on both chains.

Comment: @Ismael how would one match the transactions on both chains?

Comment: You could filter by timestamp, value, etc.